# Is it possible to get Apple Push Notifications with Firestore?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to implement APNS with Firebase Firestore?

I've managed to send a push notification to devices via Firebase Cloud Messaging from the web console but my app needs to have push notifications for changes in the database, such as when the user receive a like or a friend request.

Is there any workaround?

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) with the [FireStore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).  The first link has your use case.

There are some great [tutorial videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM) on Firebase's YouTube account.  It even includes adding a Firestore Trigger.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!

Comment: I just want to update Firestore data through Web api is it possible? My Flutter app working fine with same database.

Answer (score 2):

You can also send device-to-device push notifications, which work great for 1-1 relationships (1-1 chat, for instance). To achieve that, you can leverage this endpoint https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send.